# Add a Calculated Column to a Table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power BI, and I am struggling with adding a calculated column to a table which simply looks like this:

[image]

The column that I need to add to this table should include a list of distinct `Y` that comes with each `X`. For example `Type1` in `X` comes in total with two distinct `Y` which are `a` and `b`. So in the new column `a, b` should appear for each `Type1`, and so for all other types in `X`. Simply like this:

[image]

I guess I need to use measures in the `New Column`, but I do not know which measures and what formula in `New Column`.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with how I can add this column `Distinct Y coming with each X` to my table, or at least would you please let me know if Power BI is at all capable to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following measures:

Distinct Y for X:

```
CALCULATE ( 
    CONCATENATEX ( 
        DISTINCT ( Table1[Y] ),
        Table1[Y], 
        ", "
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[X] )
)
```

Number of Distinct Y:

```
CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Y] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[X] )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Olly, this is amazing! All works nicely! Many many thanks!